# vertical tabs shows different results between chrome,ie and firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to set up a vertical tabs by jquery UI using the css display:table,table-cell property.
But as you can see in the demo. The right cell shows an unreasonable top margin in google chrome and IE.And it works fine in firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6tbh/

```
.ui-tabs-vertical { display:table; padding:0px;  }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { display: table-cell; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { display: table-cell;margin:0px;}
```

Could someone give me an hint?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells can do what they want unless you tell them otherwise, try it like this:

```
.ui-tabs-vertical { display:table; padding:0;; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { display: table-cell;vertical-align:top; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { display: table-cell;float:left; }
```

Style the H2 for perfect results.

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F6tbh/1/